# Python: get item placements as percentage of list index divided by length

Tags: python

I have a collection of texts. Each of those texts is normalized and tokenized into a list -- I'll post that code below -- so that what I have is a list of lists, each of which is a text. What I want to do is to get all the locations of each of the words in a text.

E.g., "Here is a text; it is not a long text."

```
here: 1        (Not counting pythonically here.)
is:   2, 6
a:    3, 8
text: 4, 10
it:   5
not:  7
long: 9
```

These positions, however, aren't comparable, so I would like to normalize them by dividing them by the length of the text:

```
here: 0.1
is:   0.2, 0.6
```

My goal is then to be able to collect up **all** the instances of such words across a collection of texts and to average the locations in order to see if some words regularly occur in particular parts of the texts. This is what [David Robinson has done in R](http://varianceexplained.org/r/tidytext-plots/). I am trying to do this in Python:

```
# =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
# Data Load & Tokenize
# =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= 

import pandas
import re
from nltk.tokenize import WhitespaceTokenizer

# LOAD
colnames = ['author', 'title', 'date' , 'length', 'text']
df = pandas.read_csv('../data/talks_3.csv', names=colnames)
talks = df.text.tolist()
authors = df.author.tolist()
dates = df.date.tolist()
years = [re.sub('[A-Za-z ]', '', item) for item in dates]
authordate = [author+" "+year for author, year in zip(authors, years)]

# TOKENIZE
tokenizer = WhitespaceTokenizer()
texts = []
for talk in talks:   
    raw = re.sub(r"[^\w\d'\s]+",'', talk).lower()
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)
    texts.append(tokens)
```

And here is where I stumble -- it goes from working code to pseudo-code pretty quickly:

```
def get_word_placement(listname):
    wordplaces = {}
    for word in listname:
        get the word
        get its location of listname[word]/len(listname)
        attach those locations to word
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `enumerate` the list, then you have the index, and can divide by the length to get relative position:

**Code:**

```
word_list = 'Here is a text it is not a long text'.split()
print(word_list)

word_with_position = [
    (word, float(i)/len(word_list)) for i, word in enumerate(word_list)]
print(word_with_position)
```

**Results:**

```
['Here', 'is', 'a', 'text', 'it', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'long', 'text']

[('Here', 0.0), ('is', 0.1), ('a', 0.2), ('text', 0.3), ('it', 0.4), 
 ('is', 0.5), ('not', 0.6), ('a', 0.7), ('long', 0.8), ('text', 0.9)]
```

**As a Dict:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_with_positions = defaultdict(list)
for i, word in enumerate(word_list):
    word_with_positions[word].append(float(i)/len(word_list))

print(word_with_positions)
```

**Results:**

```
{'a': [0.2, 0.7], 'text': [0.3, 0.9], 'is': [0.1, 0.5], 'it': [0.4], 
 'Here': [0.0], 'long': [0.8], 'not': [0.6]}
```

Comment: Nice. Okay, I'm going to try this out and see if I can compile the list of tuples so that each word only appears once in the list with multiple locations -- I'll have to do that either for a single text or across the entire corpus.

Comment: You beat me to it. Thanks for unstumping!